# Running a method forever while running other methods

Tags: c#, console-application

How do I check the value of a variable constantly while running code?

I want to set something up so that no matter how it happens (subtracting, adding, setting the value) as soon as "myVar" is equal to 0, output "Dead"

```
static int myVar = 100;

public static void Main(){
  if(Console.ReadLine().Equals("kill")){
    myVar = 0;
  }
}

public static void Health(){
  while(true){
    if(myVar==0){
      Console.WriteLine("Dead");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into Threading... that's would be one way of spawning multiple threads where one of those would keep checking the value

Comment: Use a Setter for myvar, and in the setter put your if statement.

Comment: Your current code example would not result in what you describe.  Instead you would get "Dead\r\nDead\r\nDead\r\nDead\r\n".. ad infinitum.

Comment: You don't check the value of a variable constantly. Instead, you set up an event that gets fired when the value is changed and listen for that event.

Answer (score 2):

> no matter how it happens (subtracting, adding, setting the value) as soon as "myVar" is equal to 0, output "Dead"

The simplest and cleanest way of doing this is to make `myVar` a property like this:

```
private static int _myVar;
static int MyVar {
    get => _myVar;
    set {
        _myVar = value;
        if(value == 0) Console.WriteLine("Dead");
    }
}

public static void Main(){
    if(Console.ReadLine().Equals("kill")){
        MyVar = 0;
    }
}
```

In general, polling for updates is considered a very poor solution when event-driven solutions exist. In this case, you have a *setter* for the property which is executed every single time the property's value changes: thus, the instant it changes to zero, the immediate next line of code will output "Dead" instead of needing to wait for the change to be polled by some thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not how I would do things, but without more information it is hard to design something clean. Here is an example of how to use Task.Run() to run your health loop constantly while also reading console lines. I also made a recursive method so that the program does not exit after reading from the console.

```
    static int myVar = 100;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(() => Health());

        ListenForKill();
    }

    public static void Health()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (myVar == 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Dead");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ListenForKill()
    {
        if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("kill"))
        {
            myVar = 0;
        }

        //this way program won't exit
        ListenForKill();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I check the value of a variable constantly while running code?

A good way to accomplish that would be to implement a publish / subscribe solution. Your subscriber would be notified whenever the value of myvar changes. This is preferrable to the other solutions, because it requires no parallel programming, and you can isolate the logic of how you want to handle value changes in your subscriber.

```
class IntgerValueChangedPublisher
{
    public int MyVar { 
        get => _myVar; 
        set { 
            _myVar = value; 
            Publish(); 
        } 
    }

    private int _myVar = 0;
    private ICollection<IntegerValueChangedSubscriber> _subscribers = new LinkedList<IntegerValueChangedSubscriber>();

    public void Publish()
    {
        foreach(var subscriber in _subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Receive(_myVar);
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(IntegerValueChangedSubscriber subscriber)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(subscriber);
    }
}

class IntegerValueChangedSubscriber
{
    public void Receive(int value)
    {
        if (value.Equals(0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dead");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntgerValueChangedPublisher valueChangedPublisher = new IntgerValueChangedPublisher();
        IntegerValueChangedSubscriber valueChangedSubscriber = new IntegerValueChangedSubscriber();
        valueChangedPublisher.Subscribe(valueChangedSubscriber);

        while (!Console.ReadLine().Equals("kill"))
        {
            // keep looping until "kill" is entered
        }

        valueChangedPublisher.MyVar = 0;
    }
}
```